# How can I use C++ and Python in the same program

Tags: python, c++, merge

I was wondering, is there a way for me to use the programming languages, C++ and Python, in the same program?

Comment: Yes.  Are you calling C++ from Python or calling Python from C++?

Comment: I recommend searching the internet before posting to StackOverflow.  Try "Calling C++ from Python" or "Calling Python from C++".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I want to call C++ from Python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling C/C++ from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)